# Как передать данные из Js в Jsf

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, java-ee, jsf

Всем привет.Работаю с `web`-приложением.Появилась задача передать данные из `js` в `jsf2.0(PrimeFaces)` для дальнейшей обработки .Какие пути есть ?Как я могу это реализовать .Из jsf в js данные передать могу с помощью  `jQuery`  а вот оттуда в Jsf нет .Подскажите пути в каком направлении идти и так далее ...Буду безвозместно благодарен .

Comment: Ну скорее всегож можно как то иными путями получить .

Comment: мне то особо ничего ненадо только один var в котором ширина записать в java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент я нашел один способ совместимости это посредством `@ManagedBean` .Записываю туда текст и далее использую .Скорее всего этот метод кастыльный но рабочий .Постараюсь как то улучшить ответ оптимизировать но на данный момент мы имеем то что имеем :)

```
  <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="list1SortOrder" value=""#{hope.youo}> </h:inputText>
    </h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveOrder() {
      $("inputText[id*='list1SortOrder']").val("wrtie here ");
    };
</script>
```